# Explanation on Lawson's Spin Geometry book

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, differential-operators

[image]
[image]

This is from Lawson's book "Spin Geometry", specifically the beginning of chapter 3. He gives us the definition of $\textbf{differential operator of order m}$, then he makes an observation about change of local coordinates, but I don't understand what is $[\partial \tilde{x}/\partial x]_{*}^{*}$ He says that is the $\textbf{symmetrization of the mth tensor power
of the Jacobian matrix}$, but I don't know exactly what that is.

I know about symmetrization of a tensor of order m, but what is confusing me is the part of the $\textbf{mth tensor power
of the Jacobian matrix}$.

Could anyone explain me what is the author talking about?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put in all the indices, it will look like this:
$$\tilde A{}^{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_m} = \sum A^{\beta_1\dots\beta_m}\frac{\partial \tilde x^{\alpha_1}}{\partial x^{\beta_1}}\dots\frac{\partial\tilde x^{\alpha_m}}{\partial x^{\beta_m}}.$$

Comment: I'm agree with you. So that name is nothing deep?

Comment: Nope. Just the induced action of a linear map on the $m$th tensor product.

Comment: @TedShifrin can you tell me what is $\Gamma(E)$ and $E_{x}$ for the author, $E_{x}$ is in the next page when he use $\sigma_{\xi}$. in the after page he said $\Gamma(E)$ is the cross-sections of $E$, but don't know what is this. thanks

Comment: I no longer have a copy of the book, but this I can certainly answer. This is going to be a very tough book if you don't know about vector bundles. If $\pi\colon E\to M$ is a (vector) bundle, $E_x$ denotes the fiber over $x$, i.e., $\pi^{-1}(x)$. A section (or cross-section) is a smooth map $s\colon M\to E$ so that $s(x) \in E_x$ for every $x\in M$.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh thanks, so $E_{x}$ must be closed in $E$ (and too $E_{x}$ can be a set with a single point) and $\Gamma(E)$ is a set of functions

Comment: $E_x$ is a $k$-dimensional complex vector space for every $x$. Unless $k=0$ (which surely will not arise), it will never be a point. @user89940

Comment: so why pre-image $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is a vector space, what more request at $\pi$ for this. where can read more about this

Comment: As I said, you need to read some basic books on differentiable manifolds and learn what vector bundles are. Lawson/Michelsohn is a very sophisticated book.

Comment: so what book for example... if $\pi$ is surjective and $E$, $M$ are manifolds, $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is a manifold of dimension $\dim E - \dim M$ over $E$... there is my confussion.......

Answer (score 0):

The quantity $[\partial\tilde{x}/\partial x]_\beta^\alpha$ is given by
$$
  \left[\frac{\partial\tilde{x}}{\partial x}\right]_\beta^\alpha
  = \sum_{\sigma \in S_m}
  \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{\sigma(\alpha^1)}}{\partial x_{\beta^1}}
  \cdots
  \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{\sigma(\alpha^m)}}{\partial x_{\beta^m}} \qquad (1)
$$
where
$$
    \alpha^1, \ldots, \alpha^m := \underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{\alpha_1 \text{ times}}, \ldots, \underbrace{n, \ldots, n}_{\alpha_n \text{ times}}.
$$
The above formula is a sum over permutations of products of the form
$$
    \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{j_1}}{\partial x_{i_1}} \cdots \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{j_m}}{\partial x_{i_m}},
$$
and these products are exactly the entries of the $m$th [tensor power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the Jacobian matrix $\partial\tilde{x}/\partial x$, so I would guess that the matrix with entries defined by equation (1) is what they're calling the symmetrisation.
The point really is this: the two local coordinate systems $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ for $X$ induce two local frames $\{\partial^m/\partial x^\alpha\}_{\lvert\alpha\rvert=m}$ and $\{\partial^m/\partial\tilde{x}^\alpha\}_{\lvert\alpha\rvert=m}$ for the bundle $\odot^m TX$ of symmetric $(m,0)$-tensors, and the transformation law to go between these two frames is exactly
$$
    \frac{\partial^m}{\partial x^\beta}
    = \sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert=m}
    \left[\frac{\partial\tilde{x}}{\partial x}\right]_\beta^\alpha
    \frac{\partial^m}{\partial \tilde{x}^\beta}.
$$
Thus, (1) shows that the $A^\alpha$ coefficients behave like the coefficients of a section of the bundle $\odot^m TX \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(E,F)$, and this observation allows you to define the principal symbol of the differential operator $P$.

*Proof of (1)*. Let $\beta$ be a multiindex with $\lvert \beta \rvert = m$, and consider the derivative operator $\partial^m/\partial x^\beta$.
With respect to the change of coordinates $\tilde{x} = \tilde{x}(x)$, we compute
$$
    \frac{\partial^m}{\partial x^\beta}
    = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\beta^1}} \cdots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\beta^m}}
    = \left( \sum_{i_1} \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{i_1}}{\partial x_{\beta^1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde{x}_{i_1}} \right)
    \cdots
    \left( \sum_{i_m} \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{i_m}}{\partial x_{\beta^m}} \frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde{x}_{i_m}} \right).
$$
By the Leibniz rule, the order $m$ terms in the above are exactly
$$
    \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_m} \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{i_1}}{\partial x_{\beta^1}} \cdots \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{i_m}}{\partial x_{\beta^m}} \frac{\partial^m}{\partial\tilde{x}_{i_1} \cdots \partial\tilde{x}_{i_m}}.
$$
For a given multiindex $\alpha$, the terms in the above sum that have $\partial^m/\partial\tilde{x}^\alpha$ on the right are those corresponding to indices $i_1, \ldots, i_m$ which contain $\alpha_i$ $i$s for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$.
In other words, those indices $i_1, \ldots, i_m$ which are permutations of $\alpha^1, \ldots, \alpha^m$.
Hence, the above sum is equal to
$$
    \sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert=m} \sum_{\sigma \in S_m}
    \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{\sigma(\alpha^1}}{\partial x_{\beta^1}}
    \cdots
    \frac{\partial\tilde{x}_{\sigma(\alpha^m)}}{\partial x_{\beta^m}}
    \frac{\partial^m}{\partial\tilde{x}^\alpha}
    = \sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert=m} \left[\frac{\partial\tilde{x}}{\partial x}\right]_\beta^\alpha
    \frac{\partial^m}{\partial\tilde{x}^\alpha}.
$$
Substituting this into
$$
    P = \sum_{\lvert\beta\rvert\leq m} A^\beta \frac{\partial^{\lvert\beta\rvert}}{\partial x^\beta}
     = \sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq m} \tilde{A}^\alpha \frac{\partial^{\lvert\alpha\rvert}}{\partial\tilde{x}^\alpha}
$$
and equating the coefficients of the $m$th order derivatives yields
$$
    \tilde{A}^\alpha = \sum_{\lvert\beta\rvert=m} A^\beta \left[\frac{\partial\tilde{x}}{\partial x}\right]_\beta^\alpha,
$$
as desired.